# Confusion with async functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Please note that I am a total noob when it comes to Node.js.

I have created a WebSockets app that will send server status and usage every second when a client connects (through basic authentications so that only the authorized clients can contact).

I want to add disk usage info to the data and is using the [nodejs-disks](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodejs-disks) module for that. And this is the function I've created to get the info I need:

```
function getDiskStats()
{
    var output = {
        count: 0,
        space: {
            total: 0,
            used: 0,
            free: 0
        }
    };

    df.drives(function(err, drives)
    {
        df.drivesDetail(drives, function(err, data)
        {
            output.count = data.length;

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                output.space.total += parseInt(data[i].total);
                output.space.used += parseInt(data[i].used);
                output.space.free += parseInt(data[i].available)
            }
        });
    });

    return output;
}
```

But when the output is returned, everything is 0 and if I log variable in the console right after the `for` loop I get the values. My guess is that its because of the async method `nodejs-disks` uses to get the data. I am not sure what I should do next and I HAVE google a lot but couldn't find a good solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @mevernom said, you are returning your object before any of the asynchronous objects have a chance to work.

You can modify your function to work asynchronously by making your `getDiskStats` function take a callback that it calls when everything else is done.

```
function getDiskStats(callback) {
    var output = {
        count: 0,
        space: {
            total: 0,
            used: 0,
            free: 0
        }
    };

    df.drives(function(err, drives) {
        if (err) return callback(err); // stop on error

        df.drivesDetail(drives, function(err, data) {
            if (err) return callback(err); // stop on error

            output.count = data.length;

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                output.space.total += parseInt(data[i].total);
                output.space.used += parseInt(data[i].used);
                output.space.free += parseInt(data[i].available)
            }

            // done processing, call callback
            callback(null, output);
        });
    });
}
```

You would then have to use your function like

```
getDiskStats(function(err, value) {
    // do stuff!
});
```

Comment: Never thought of that... lol... Another thing: I have to use the sendText function of the WS Server inside the callback, right? Since it will still be async if the output is called outside the function and the disk details will still be null.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `getDistStats` returned immediately, before callbacks finished their tasks.
If you are not comfortable with asynchronous nature, perhaps you could try [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) module.

Comment: Can you provide me a code for the work around? Thanks!